# Favour foreground app not working for HCE payments Android

Tags: nfc, android-pay, point-of-sale, hce

I'm facing a strange issue in my HCE payments. I have two payments application in my mobile. One was developed by me and other is Android pay. In Tap&Pay the default one is "Android Pay" and my app is non-default and enabled "Favour foreground app".

Now my problem is when I try to make payments (Tap device to POS), the device always prompting "Android Pay" instead of my app.

I followed all guidelines given in Android documentation.

[Android HCE guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html)

Do I need to enable anything in my code to make this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to leverage the "Favor Foreground App" preference, you need to tell [`CardEmulation`](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation.html) that your app is ready to intercept the terminal tap.  By default, your app won't intercept the tap.

In our app, I do this in onPause() and onResume() in each Activity (or you can extend a common Activity and just do this once.

in [**onResume()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation.html) call
`public boolean setPreferredService (Activity activity, ComponentName service)`

in [**onPause()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/nfc/cardemulation/CardEmulation.html#unsetPreferredService(android.app.Activity)), call 
`public boolean unsetPreferredService (Activity activity)`